# Set imageView from Thread

Tags: java, android

I am using a freind to download a picture and set in the `ImageView`; however, I get this error:

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

This is my code.

```
ImageView profilePicture =....
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        profilePic.setImageBitmap(image_profile);
    }
};
thread.start();
```

The image_profile `Bitmap` is a valid `Bitmap` file. (I checked it via debug.)

This thread is running in the `OnCreate` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update ui on another thread. **Update ui on the main ui thread** as below

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
    {
        public void run() 
        { 
            profilePic.setImageBitmap(image_profile);

        }
    });
    }
    };
   thread.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot update your UI directly from the `Thread`. Instead, use `runOnUiThread()` or equivalent.

**Replace this**:

```
profilePic.setImageBitmap(image_profile);
```

**With this**:

```
YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        profilePic.setImageBitmap(image_profile);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't about the `Bitmap`. The problem is that you are trying to do `UI` stuff in a separate `Thread`. With the code you've given, there is no reason for the `Thread`. Remove the `Thread`. If you are doing other things that you aren't showing then you can use [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and update the `ImageView` in any method other than `doInBackground()` as it doesn't run on the `UI`